# How to get Xcode 8 Code Coverage for embedded framework using UI Unit Tests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, xcode8.2

Here's my set up:

One Xcode 8 Workspace project
     Swift Framework with lots of UI code (UIViewControllers, etc.)
     Objective C Example App

For both projects, the Code Coverage setting is checked in the Test scheme.

I would like to run automated UI tests using the Example App to exercise code in the Framework project. This works. However, I don't get any code coverage for the referenced framework.

There's quite a lot of UI code, so it would be very useful to get these code coverage numbers.

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 (but I've also tried in Xcode 8.3 beta 1).

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage flag in Xcode is found by
Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
Select Test from the left menu
Click on the checkbox for gather code coverage.

Next time you run your tests, you'll see the coverage in the Report Navigator, and selecting the test that just ran.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have this setting enabled for both project schemes. I updated the question. In any case, it still does not work

Comment: Oh I understand now. That's not possible. Apple hasn't included the UI coverage in its test report, only the unit test coverage. My team spent a month looking into this and trying third party options, not possible with any of them. Many have complained to apple but no resolve yet.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10 version 10.2 beta now has support for capturing code coverage with embedded frameworks run under the context of an app running UI tests :)

https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Could you please share some reference links? Would be helpful and get a way.